Can I repurpose a 60 Amp AC circuit for subpanel?
I have a 200 amp SD outdoor service entrance. Currently there is 60 amp breaker that runs my AC/heat pump. I want to do away with the AC/heat pump and install two 240V 18000 BTU mini splits. Can I use a 60 amp subpanel and split into two 30amp circuits? If so, where to find one? I would like to use the #6-3 wire to supply the sub and #10-2 wire to supply the mini splits.

Might want to shop harder on the mini-splits if they need 30A to do 18K BTU. My 12K units only need a 15A 240V circuit (actual MCA of 10.9A)

Also How can I split a 240 breaker into two 120 circuits? and Can I reuse a 240V heating circuit's breaker for a shed feeder?

You do not need to limit yourself to an exactly 60 amp panel.  A bigger amp panel will be okay to use, but still limited to only using 60 amps.
